# Are there any RavenDb client libraries that work with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, ravendb

I'm building an app using Xamarin and was wondering if there are any RavenDb libraries that can be distributed with Xamarin apps to ease development with making server side calls and also wondering if there is a client side "lite" version of RavenDb.

Answer (score 0):

The client `Raven.Client.Lightweight` should work with no issue with Xamarin.

Comment: sorry to unaccept this answer but it seems that the Raven.Client.Lightweight is incompatible when using Xamarin's new shared project solution.  I get the following build error when attempting to use the lightweight client:  Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Comment: Where do things stand with this?

Comment: @ayende-rahien, trying to install the package [RavenDB Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/3.5.0-rc-35166) (latest prerelease) fails with: _the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework_. Trying to add a reference by hand leads to a runtime error during deployment (similiar to [this issue](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RavenDB/issues/85)). Any hope?